# Deduce an unspecified polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm having a little trouble with problems that have an unspecified polynomial, for example $p(x)$, and having to get properties of them. A problem I ran across had something along the lines of $p(x) \div (x-25)=0$, then asked to find for which values of $p(x)$ make this statement true. Examples include $p(25)=0$, etc. I know that $p(x)$ is not 25, because dividing by zero is impossible.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You don’t mean *ambiguous*: you mean *unspecified*.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the correction.

Comment: I think you have stated the conditions erroneously.  ${p(x)\over x-25}=0$ can only have solutions where $p(x)=0$, and probably also $x\ne 25$ although that depends somewhat on the degree of $p(x)$.

Comment: That's where I got confused. The question I wrote is how it appeared. It was multiple choice, so it had options such as $p(-25)=0$, $p(-5)=0$, etc.

Comment: What is the definition of your $\div$? I suspect $f(x) \div g(x)$ is either the quotient $q(x)$ or the remainder $r(x)$ when you perform a long division of the polynomial $f(x) = g(x)q(x)+r(x)$ by polynomial $g(x)$.

Comment: Here's an example of that type of question. Maybe it will make it clearer than saying it in words. http://i.imgur.com/uURR24w.png

Comment: Well, the polynomial may not be ambiguous, but the question surely is. I think achille is probably right and we're saying the remainder is $0$...if $p(x)\div (x-25)$ denotes the quotient then all 4 choices are true.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering the same thing when I saw the question. I just thought there was some way of solving it.

Comment: Based on the actual question, I think $\div$ means taking the remainder. In the case, we will have an unique answer $p(25) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks @achillehui, do you mind explaining how the 25 goes into the actual function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement $p(x) \div (x-25) = 0$ is ambiguous, there are 3 possible interpretations of it.

1. ordinary division as a rational function $\frac{p(x)}{x-25} = 0$.
2. the quotient $q(x)$ in a long division is zero.
3. the remainder $r(x)$ in a long division is zero.

In the $2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ interpretation, the function $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ are uniquely determined by the expansion of 
$$p(x)\quad\text{ as }\quad q(x)(x - 5) + r(x)$$
where $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ are polynomials. Furthermore, $\deg r(x) < \deg(x-5) = 1$ forces $r(x)$ to be a constant.

In the original multiple-choice question, it asks which one of the four values $p(\pm 5)$, $p(\pm 25)$ is zero.

1. In the $1^{st}$ interpretation, $p(x) = 0$ identically. This means $p(\pm 5) = p(\pm 25) = 0$. So the MC doesn't have an unique solution.
2. In the $2^{nd}$ interpretation, $q(x) = 0$ implies $p(x) = r(x)$. Since $r(x)$  is a constant, either all or none of $p(\pm 5), p(\pm 25) = 0$. Once again, the MC
   doesn't have an unique solution.
3. In the $3^{rd}$ interpretation, $r(x) = 0$ implies $p(x)$ can be factorized as
   $q(x)(x-25)$. From this, we get $p(25) = q(25)(25 - 25) = 0$. We don't have any information about what happens at $p(\pm 5)$ or $p(-25)$.

Combine these observations, it is a safe bet the $\div$ in the original question means taking the remainder and the answer of the MC is $p(25) = 0$.

Comment: Awesome, I think I understand it well now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the only way to get $A/B = 0$ is  $A=0$.